# Arduino NearBus NearbusEther_v16.h: No such file or directory

Tags: android, web, arduino, cloud

I am working on a project with arduino, i am using NearBus connect my arduino to cloud. I am using api downloaded from NearBus but when i load it an compile it says "NearbusEther_v16.h: No such file or directory" although file is available in libraries folder.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used

```
#include "NearbusEther_v16.h"
```

or

```
#include <NearbusEther_v16.h>
```

?

There is a difference.  Also did you try manually adding the file through the Sketch>Add File dialog?